# Sequential Highlighting of a UILabels with sound clips

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, highlighting

I have been searching for a answer for this issue for a while now, and haven't had any luck.

Here is the issue: I have four UILabels, and sound clips to go with them.  I want each label to show highlighted text when it's sound clip is played.

The problem is that only the last label is gets highlighted when I test it on simulator.

Here are some things that I've tried:

```
[self playSound:@"this"];
[thisLabel setTextColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
sleep(1);
[self playSound:@"is"];
[thisLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[isLabel setTextColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[self playSound:@"a"];
[isLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[aLabel setTextColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[self playSound:@"word"];
[aLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[currentWord setTextColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

This is when I discovered that only the last label would show up highlighted when I tested it in the simulator.

The next thing I tried is putting a call to this function at the end of t he playSound function.

```
- (void)shiftHighlight:(NSString *)word
{
    UILabel *currentWord = [self currentWord];
    UILabel *thisLabel = [self thisLabel];
    UILabel *isLabel = [self isLabel];
    UILabel *aLabel = [self aLabel];
    if ([word isEqualToString:@"this"])
    {
        [thisLabel setHighlighted:YES];

        [isLabel setHighlighted:NO];
        [aLabel setHighlighted:NO];
        [currentWord setHighlighted:NO];
    } else if ([word isEqualToString:@"is"]) {
        [isLabel setHighlighted:YES];

        [thisLabel setHighlighted:NO];
        [aLabel setHighlighted:NO];
        [currentWord setHighlighted:NO];
    } else if ([word isEqualToString:@"a"]) {
        [aLabel setHighlighted:YES];

        [thisLabel setHighlighted:NO];
        [isLabel setHighlighted:NO];
        [currentWord setHighlighted:NO];
    } else {
        [currentWord setHighlighted:YES];

        [thisLabel setHighlighted:NO];
        [isLabel setHighlighted:NO];
        [aLabel setHighlighted:NO];
    }
}
```

With the color of the highlighted text set as orange elsewhere.
This had the same effect as the first attempt.

Most recently I tried putting successive calls to this function:

```
- (void)readSection:(NSString *)section
{
    [self playSound:section];
    [self shiftHighlight:section];
}
```

I've also tried something with NSTimers, but that got very confusing and it seemed like I was barking up the wrong tree with them.

Behavior is enabled on all labels.

So, if anyone has a solution for me, or can carefully explain how to use NSTimers for this issue, I'd her very thankful.

Comment: What framework or method are you using for playing the sound. i.e the actual method that plays the sound?

Comment: With timers it could have worked, but then you would have to know the exact time for which the sound will be played and code accordingly. There would definitely be better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all cases the statements are not waiting for the sound to finish playing and gets executed before-hand in the order of occurrence. The last statement executed will be the final result, i.e the final label being highlighted.
 If your playSound method has a way to pass a call-back block or a delegate function that gets executed after completion that is the place where you should be writing the logic to the highlight label or play the next sound.

Comment: I suppose it's time to research call-back blocks and delegate functions.  Thank you!

Comment: Don't start blindly researching on call-backs and delegates, although it would be a good thing. For solving this particular problem you might need to look more into how your sound is played and how to call your methods after the sound is played.

Comment: @Leona: the up and down arrows to the left of an answer and question describes its usefulness. If you found the answer useful you can press the up arrow to give an up-vote.

Comment: Yeah, but it requires more reputation than I seem to have. :/  I most certianly would if I could though.

Comment: So, since I was using the Audio Services system sound functions, I was able to use their sound finished call backs!  I finally figured out how to use them properly, and I've got everything working right!  Hurray!